# Error during Magento Installation

Tags: php, magento, xdebug, magento2, magento-2.0

I am trying to install Magento 2 on my localhost but it is giving me the following error during readiness check.

```
PHP Settings Check
Your current setting of xdebug.max_nesting_level=100. Magento 2 requires it to be set to 200 or more. Edit your config, restart web server, and try again.
```

I searched for `xdebug.max_nesting_level` in my entire wamp but did not found any such phrase. Opened my `php.ini` file. The last lines were these.

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "d:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

So I added extra line below it.

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200
```

But Installation is still giving me same error. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you restart your apache service?

Edit:

Add 'php_value xdebug.max_nesting_level 500' to your .htaccess

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but i notice that xdebug.remote_enable & xdebug.profiler_enable are both 'off', have you tried turning them on one at a time? Not entirely sure, but may be worth a shot :)

Comment: Try adding: 'php_value xdebug.max_nesting_level 500' to your .htaccess

Comment: Awesome :) No problem :) Good luck further!